# CUDA out of memory when I have plenty

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a NVidia GTX 1060 6GB Edition GPU. When I try rendering my scene, I get that error. It peaks at only 5GB, meaning I still have 1GB of memory left. However, I'm still getting the error. I could just render with my CPU, and I have, however, I really want to use my GPU because it renders like 3x faster. Any ideas that could help?

Comment: Use GPU-Z to see the real number for vRAM usage. Also keep in mind that if there are monitors connected to the card you are using some of that vRAM for whatever is on the screen. Optimize your scene to make it renderable or render in pieces and then composite later.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68023/gtx-970-blender278-cuda-error/68505#68505 and https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: I had it open while I was rendering, and I only hit about 5.4 Gb's at max.

Comment: Memory often isn't allocated gradually in small pieces, if a step knows that it will need 1GB of ram to hold the data for the task then it will allocate it in one lot. So while 5.4GB is being used and cycles asks to allocate 700MB it will fail and the render stops.

Comment: A hugely overlooked feature is the simplify section in the scene panel.  Too many subdivisions globally can cause memory crashes.  Make sure the render section is set to no more than 2 or 3 subdivisions.  For most purposes, this should suffice and prevent memory errors.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I really am out of Memory then, kinda sucks. I just ran another render on my cpu and it hit like 12 Gb. I'm gonna get two 1080's in SLI at some point, so that should solve it

Comment: 2 Cards might not be the magic solution either. Keep in mind that adding multiple cards does not mean that the memory of the cards is added into a common pool. VRAM is not shared, but limited by the size of the smallest card on the system. Two cards with 8GB is not 16GB but 8 usable GB per card. You need to optimize your scene or break it up in parts that are renderable and composite the pieces together.

Comment: @cegaton aka render layers

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing